# How can I make a element scroll-able if set to 'overflow-x: auto', without showing the scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<style>
  .homePagePosters {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
  }

  .homePagePosters--img img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
  }
.homePagePosters::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<div class='homePagePosters'>
  <div class="homePagePosters--img">
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/260/190?random=1' alt='1'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/260/190?random=2' alt='2'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/260/190?random=3' alt='3'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/260/190?random=4' alt='4'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/260/190?random=5' alt='5'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/260/190?random=6' alt='6'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/260/190?random=7' alt='7'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/260/190?random=8' alt='8'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/260/190?random=9' alt='9'>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/260/190?random=10' alt='10'>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make class `homePagePosters` scroll-able in non-touch-screen devices, without showing the scrollbar?

When I tried to scroll the div with the mouse click the image was getting dragged.

Comment: you need to use `javascript` to make the scroll draggable

Comment: @fevid Can you tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're on right track with targeting `::-webkit-scrollbar`, as this will hide the scrollbars for Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

For hiding scrollbar on Internet Explorer and Edge, use: `-ms-overflow-style: none`

For hiding scrollbar on [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width), use: `scrollbar-width: none`